# DataGrid Scrolling not working

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone

I have a datagrid which is populated using data retrieved from a database.  Unfortunately, when the number of rows retrieved is more than the height of the datagrid, I cannot scroll vertically or horizontally, even though both scrollbars are shown.

Here is my code:

```
        <data:DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid_Transactions" AutoGenerateColumns="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="300" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Background="#FF0F1111" FontSize="26" Foreground="RoyalBlue" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="AliceBlue" IsReadOnly="True" VerticalGridLinesBrush="AliceBlue" AlternatingRowBackground="AliceBlue" FontFamily="Segoe WP SemiLight" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible" RowBackground="AliceBlue">
            <data:DataGrid.Columns>
                <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Transaction ID" Binding="{Binding TransactionID}" />
                <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Vendor Username" Binding="{Binding VendorUsername}" />
                <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Purchase Description" Binding="{Binding PurchaseDescription}" />
                <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Total Price" Binding="{Binding TotalPrice}" />
                <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Currency" Binding="{Binding Currency}" />
            </data:DataGrid.Columns>
        </data:DataGrid>
        <Button Content="Main Page" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,540,0,43" Name="Button_MainPage" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="456" Click="Button_MainPage_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Can someone please help me?  Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems attached property does not work directly for this type objects,
Even it works for ListBox(http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Tip-How-to-specify-ScrollViewer-s-attached-properties-in-XAML.aspx)

You should put it in a ScrollViewer

```
<ScrollViewer ...>
       content
</ScrollViewer>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer(v=vs.95).aspx

For another way, have a look this attached property coding tip
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/95746/Exposing-and-Binding-to-a-Silverlight-ScrollViewer

You may also code your own attached property.(you shoud use RegisterAttached while dependency object registration,and obey attached property coding rules.)

Comment: Thanks.  At last I solved it by putting a scrollviewer around the entire page (vertical enabled and horizontal disabled) as well as a scrollviewer just before the datagrid (vertical disabled and horizontal enabled).  I set the height of the datagrid to auto.  I know this is not the best way to go around the problem but at least it works.

Answer (score 0):

**I have working code :**

```
<sdk:DataGrid x:Name="dgList" Margin="0" HeadersVisibility="All" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Single" UseLayoutRounding="True" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FFA2B4D3">
<sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DOCTORNO}" Header="No" />
    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DOCTORNAME}" Header="Ad Soyad" />
    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding UZMANLIKKODU}" Header="Branş" />
    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding BRANSAD}" Header="Branş Adı" />
</sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
```